# What is the difference for a Mandir to be erected on the left bank vs right bank of a river?

Tags: vedas, temple, upanishads

What is the difference for a Mandir to be erected on the  left bank vs right bank of a river?

Is it related to the Deity, or perhaps to the place?

Do the Vedas, Upanishads or various Agamas prescribe which place is better, for a given Mandir?

Comment: Don't think that Vedas will have any prescription for temple building (they may have for the location of yajnas). It's the various Agamas that may have such things.

Comment: Thank you, I have amended the question.

Comment: Not specific to temples, but if you read tirtha Yatra parva in Mahabharata, it talks about rishis asylums on both south and north banks of rivers. So, I don't think there is much difference.